# What type of javascript syntax is this?

Tags: javascript, oop, syntax

I am trying to get to know some code from a third party opensource project.

I have been programming in JS for some time, but I am not versed in the object oriented or functional programming part if it as yet.

I have read about how javascript is a prototype language and about design patterns that can give you 'object oriented like' functionality such as inheritance etc. So I will get there eventually.

I am trying to figure out what type of syntax the following is, so that I can focus on getting to know that, as I will of course need it for my future programming on a project.

If someone can please help me out in helping identify the syntax used here, and point me to some references where I can read about it online, that would be extremely helpful.

Thanks,
Harriet

```js
WaveSurfer.Regions = {
    init: function (wavesurfer) {
        this.wavesurfer = wavesurfer;
        this.wrapper = this.wavesurfer.drawer.wrapper;

        /* Id-based hash of regions. */
        this.list = {};
    },

    /* Add a region. */
    add: function (params) {
        var region = Object.create(WaveSurfer.Region);
        region.init(params, this.wavesurfer);

        this.list[region.id] = region;

        region.on('remove', (function () {
            delete this.list[region.id];
        }).bind(this));

        return region;
    },

    /* Remove all regions. */
    clear: function () {
        Object.keys(this.list).forEach(function (id) {
            this.list[id].remove();
        }, this);
    },

    enableDragSelection: function (params) {
        var my = this;
        var drag;
        var start;
        var region;

        function eventDown(e) {
            drag = true;
            if (typeof e.targetTouches !== 'undefined' && e.targetTouches.length === 1) {
                e.clientX = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
            }
            start = my.wavesurfer.drawer.handleEvent(e);
            region = null;
        }
        this.wrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', eventDown);
        this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchstart', eventDown);
        this.on('disable-drag-selection', function() {
            my.wrapper.removeEventListener('touchstart', eventDown);
            my.wrapper.removeEventListener('mousedown', eventDown);
        });
        function eventUp(e) {
            drag = false;

            if (region) {
                region.fireEvent('update-end', e);
                my.wavesurfer.fireEvent('region-update-end', region, e);
            }

            region = null;
        }
        this.wrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', eventUp);
        this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchend', eventUp);
        this.on('disable-drag-selection', function() {
            my.wrapper.removeEventListener('touchend', eventUp);
            my.wrapper.removeEventListener('mouseup', eventUp);
        });
        function eventMove(e) {
            if (!drag) { return; }

            if (!region) {
                region = my.add(params || {});
            }

            var duration = my.wavesurfer.getDuration();
            if (typeof e.targetTouches !== 'undefined' && e.targetTouches.length === 1) {
                e.clientX = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
            }
            var end = my.wavesurfer.drawer.handleEvent(e);
            region.update({
                start: Math.min(end * duration, start * duration),
                end: Math.max(end * duration, start * duration)
            });
        }
        this.wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMove);
        this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchmove', eventMove);
        this.on('disable-drag-selection', function() {
            my.wrapper.removeEventListener('touchmove', eventMove);
            my.wrapper.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMove);
        });
    },

    disableDragSelection: function () {
        this.fireEvent('disable-drag-selection');
    }
};
```

Comment: It's an object literal. Nothing much more fancy than that.

Comment: That looks quite straightforward. Which parts are you having problem with?

Comment: The problem I have is that there is another piece of code that follows the same pattern - and it fires an event handler. I registered to receive notification on this event handler, but need to make a call I cannot figure out how to make... Here is an example if that will help. http://codepen.io/BusyBee/pen/bwXYmx

Comment: Here is an example if that will help. http://codepen.io/BusyBee/pen/bwXYmx. The event is 'region-update-end'. In this on event handler I need to make a call to update a property on another object, that is passed to the event handler. Unfortunately I do not know how to reference it.

Comment: @Harriet in that example and in that event handler, you have `wavesurfer.seekTo(region.start);` but `region` is not defined inside the handler. Is it supposed to be passed in or maybe was it supposed to be `wavesurfer.region` (this is used in the next line) or something? I'm sorry if I'm not being helpful - I'm unfamiliar with the API, so I'm only going off what I can see there.

Comment: @Harriet actually, see if [this works](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyBvGe) I added `region` to the handler (`function(region)`) and then changed `wavesurfer.region` to just `region`. It seems it's not throwing errors any more. Not sure if it's working as you expect it, though.

Comment: I will quickly check out your link, brb

Comment: @vlaz, thank you for helping out, that is exactly what I wanted to try out... (although it does not 100% do what I thought it would do - i am trying to get the cursor to move to the start of the region, so it would play from that position)

Comment: @Harriet again - I'm unfamiliar with the API. I just stopped it from throwing errors, so I'm hoping this is enough for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WaveSurfer is a global property on the window object.

Regions is an object on the WaveSurfer object.

The Regions object is declared using a JavaScript object literal notation, which is very similar to JSON notation. However, a JavaScript object literal can have functions as property values.

So Regions has the following functions available on it ... add, clear, etc

```
WaveSurfer.Regions = {
init: function (wavesurfer) {
    this.wavesurfer = wavesurfer;
    this.wrapper = this.wavesurfer.drawer.wrapper;

    /* Id-based hash of regions. */
    this.list = {};
},

/* Add a region. */
add: function (params) {
    var region = Object.create(WaveSurfer.Region);
    region.init(params, this.wavesurfer);

    this.list[region.id] = region;

    region.on('remove', (function () {
        delete this.list[region.id];
    }).bind(this));

    return region;
},

/* Remove all regions. */
clear: function () {
    Object.keys(this.list).forEach(function (id) {
        this.list[id].remove();
    }, this);
},

enableDragSelection: function (params) {
    var my = this;
    var drag;
    var start;
    var region;

    function eventDown(e) {
        drag = true;
        if (typeof e.targetTouches !== 'undefined' && e.targetTouches.length === 1) {
            e.clientX = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
        }
        start = my.wavesurfer.drawer.handleEvent(e);
        region = null;
    }
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', eventDown);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchstart', eventDown);
    this.on('disable-drag-selection', function() {
        my.wrapper.removeEventListener('touchstart', eventDown);
        my.wrapper.removeEventListener('mousedown', eventDown);
    });
    function eventUp(e) {
        drag = false;

        if (region) {
            region.fireEvent('update-end', e);
            my.wavesurfer.fireEvent('region-update-end', region, e);
        }

        region = null;
    }
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', eventUp);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchend', eventUp);
    this.on('disable-drag-selection', function() {
        my.wrapper.removeEventListener('touchend', eventUp);
        my.wrapper.removeEventListener('mouseup', eventUp);
    });
    function eventMove(e) {
        if (!drag) { return; }

        if (!region) {
            region = my.add(params || {});
        }

        var duration = my.wavesurfer.getDuration();
        if (typeof e.targetTouches !== 'undefined' && e.targetTouches.length === 1) {
            e.clientX = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
        }
        var end = my.wavesurfer.drawer.handleEvent(e);
        region.update({
            start: Math.min(end * duration, start * duration),
            end: Math.max(end * duration, start * duration)
        });
    }
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMove);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchmove', eventMove);
    this.on('disable-drag-selection', function() {
        my.wrapper.removeEventListener('touchmove', eventMove);
        my.wrapper.removeEventListener('mousemove', eventMove);
    });
},

disableDragSelection: function () {
    this.fireEvent('disable-drag-selection');
}
};
```

Comment: Say I have in another js file, an instance of the WaveSurfer object, called wavesurfer. How do I reference the Regions object, or how do I make method calls to the methods defined above?

Comment: wavsurfer.Regions.clear();   wavsurfer.Regions.add(params);